# Is there a way to create a custom plugin for CK Editor to support inline SVGs?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I want to create a plugin that lets users insert a widget with a SVG icon and some text. I created the widget that allows the user to add text but when I try to add an SVG it striped all of my attributes out. Is there a way to allow inline SVGs inside of the editor. I can not find any documentation on SVG support.

```
schema.register('actionIcon', {
      allowWhere: '$text',
      isInline: true
      allowAttributes: ['name', 'class']
    })

schema.register('actionCircle', {
      allowWhere: '$text',
      isInline: true,
      allowAttributes: ['name', 'class', 'cx', 'cy', 'r', 'stroke', 'fill']
    })

// ...

conversion.elementToElement({
      model: 'actionIcon',
      view: {
        name: 'svg',
        classes: 'action-icon'
      }
})

conversion.elementToElement({
      model: 'actionCircle',
      view: {
        name: 'circle',
        classes: 'action-circle',
        ['cx']: '50',
        ['cy']: '50',
        ['r']: '40',
        ['stroke']: 'green',
        ['fill']: 'yellow'
      }
})


Result:

<p>
    <svg class="action-icon">
        <circle class="action-circle">&nbsp;</circle>
    </svg>
    <span class="placeholder ck-widget" contenteditable="false">
        Item
    </span>
</p>
```

I expected to create a scheme and converter for an svg and insert that into the widget but ck editor strips away all the attributes I verbosely defined.

Comment: I haven't been able to work this out either. The documentation seems to say to extend the GeneralHtmlSupport and I have tried registering SVG as an inline element but to no avail: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/general-html-support.html#enabling-custom-elements

Comment: Was there still nobody able to configure this feature to CKeditor? Its such a common use-case to embedd SVG to an HTML structure, somehow that must be possible! An ugly workaround is to just add a class-name and creating a JavaScript which inserts the SVG on runtime... but thats a really bad solution.

Comment: See below for the solution. Note, you can also try a variation of `CKEDITOR.config.extraAllowedContent = 'svg[*]{*}(*); path[*]{*}(*);';`, but you will need to add all of the sub types with would be a pain, but this is more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but...

You need to disable the advanced content filter. It will strip out SVGs due to security concerns.

`CKEDITOR.config.allowedContent = true;`